# Anywhere to download Repo script

Tags: android, android-source

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html directs users to download the repo script from kernel.org, but, the 'android.git.kernel.org is currently down. Are there any other mirrors?

Code:

```
$ curl https://android.git.kernel.org/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

Error:

> curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'android.git.kernel.org'

Comment: I don't this this is really an appropriate question for stack overflow. It's only tangentially related to programming, and it's very transient in nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While kernel.org is down you can find the full Android sources at http://github.com/android  and the repo script can be found at https://github.com/android/tools_repo